# Geometrically twisting a speed-measurement?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

This should be easy, but I need help understanding and coming up with a sound solution to this problem:

"You are controlling the speed of cars that drive across a straight road using a laser gun.
Your position is next to a bush 20 meters away from the road. A car drives past, and you
point your laser gun towards it. When the car passes a mark that you’ve placed 40 meters away
from the point closest to where you’re standing, you make the measurement. The result shows that
the distance between the gun and the car in that exact moment is increasing by 105 km/h. How fast
is the car driving at that exact time?"

[Visual representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQDVx.png)

(It should say 20 meters on the left side, the picture got a little cut off)

As you can see, it's a perpendicular triangle, so I can make out the last distance between the laser gun and the car to be about 44.7 m using the Pythagorean theorem easily.

The next steps is where I'm a little confused and not sure how to proceed. I understand that we are measuring the speed from our point of view, and need to find a way to calculate this speed as if it were taken directly on the straight road. Is there a way to simply twist our point of view algebraically? I understand we need trig, but how?

Comment: Interesting because I was out last night doing exactly that! It was called the "cosine effect" in police training but in fact they would never use anything other than the reading on the speed gun in a court of law.

Comment: Have you learned about resolving forces into components? That is what the usual name is for what you (accurately) describe as twisting our point of view.

Comment: @tomi I'm afraid not. My physics-background is weak to say the least.

Comment: Look at this: http://copradar.com/preview/chapt2/ch2d1.html